# Migration css rails login form to bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

Need help migration to bootstrap.

bootstrap sound easy just go get all scss and samples to paste. But I don't know how to insert "@user, url: signup_path" into/or replace in bootstrap code to work in rails app.

html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap code: from [getbootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-sizing)

```
<div class="input-group input-group-lg">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">
</div>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2">
</div>

<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon3">@</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3">
</div>
```

Updated:
bootstrap as follow:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>
  <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
   </div>

  <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: signup_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon1">@</span>
   <%= f.input :name,  input_html: {class: 'form-control'}, placeholder: 'Name' %>
 </div>

 <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">@</span>
  <%= f.input :email,  input_html: {class: 'form-control'}, placeholder: 'Email' %>
 </div>

 <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon3">@</span>
  <%= f.password_field :password,  input_html: {class: 'form-control'}, placeholder: 'Password' %>
 </div>
 <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I hope you get the idea!

Comment: NoMethodError in Users#new
Showing ../app/views/users/new.html.erb where line #13 raised:

undefined method `input' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007f8f5dd39f70>  Thk.

Comment: install this **simple_form_for** gem https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form & change `form_for` to simple_form_for`. Thanks

Comment: Now It's Worked ! /Thk. (This is the first one explained after I tried all previous Q.